# Android Lollipop Soft Keyboard Hides User Inputs in DialogFragment

Tags: android, scrollview, android-softkeyboard, android-dialogfragment, dialogfragment

I am writing my first real Android application. I have an Android `DialogFragment` that I am displaying to allow users to add or edit details of a selected item. The DialogFragment pops up and displays fine in full screen mode. However, on the Lollipop emulator when I click on `EditText` widgets that are lower on the screen, the soft keyboard covers up the widget, rather than scrolling the screen up so that the user may see what they are typing. I do NOT experience this behavior in the pre-Lollipop emulator. On the KitKat emulator, the screen adjusts so that the `EditText` is still visible. StackOverflow will not let me post pictures yet. So, you'll have to use your imagination. :-( I have tried different ways to overcome this issue. Unfortunately, none have worked for Lollipop.

**UPDATE** - I have tested this on a Sony Xperia Z3 Compact running Android 5.0.2, and the `DialogFragment` does not scroll or adjust the screen when selecting the lower `EditText` widgets.

Here are the styles in use:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryText</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorSecondaryText</item>
    <item name="android:dialogTheme">@style/DialogTheme</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/AppActionBarTheme</item>"
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppActionBarTheme</item>
    <item name="actionBarPopupTheme">@style/AppActionBarOverflowMenuTheme</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="android:clickable">true</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">stateHidden|adjustResize</item>
    <item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

As you can see in the `DialogTheme`, I have included the `android:windowSoftInputMode` attribute. I have also tried using that attribute in the AndroidManifest.xml file under the Activity that ultimately contains the `DialogFragment`. Here is the XML layout file for the `DialogFragment`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.ahappydevelopment.android.fishtales.views.LogEditView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dialog_margin_top"
    android:background="@color/background_material_light"
    android:theme="@style/DialogTheme">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar_edit" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCatchDate"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCatchTime"
                style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:textAllCaps="false" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editLatitudeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnCatchDate"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/label_latitude"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editLongitudeLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/editLatitudeLabel"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/label_longitude"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgCatchPicture"
                android:layout_width="75dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/editLatitudeLabel"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgcatchpicture_contentdescription"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerLocation"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/editLongitudeLabel" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFishHeader"
                style="?android:attr/listSeparatorTextViewStyle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinnerLocation"
                android:text="@string/section_fish" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerSpeciesType"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/txtFishHeader" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editLengthLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinnerSpeciesType"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="@string/hint_length"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editWeightLabel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/spinnerSpeciesType"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="@string/hint_weight"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editLengthLabel2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/editLengthLabel"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="@string/hint_length"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editWeightLabel2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/editWeightLabel"
                android:ems="5"
                android:hint="@string/hint_weight"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

        </RelativeLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</com.ahappydevelopment.android.fishtales.views.LogEditView>
```

As you can see, my layout does include a `ScrollView`. I have even defined the `android:theme="@style/DialogTheme"` in the layout. I have tried setting `android:fillViewport="true"` on the ScrollView, as I saw in another StackOverflow posting.

On the Java side of things, I have an override for the `onCreateDialog` method defined as such:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Dialog dialog = new Dialog(getActivity(), R.style.DialogTheme);
    //set to adjust screen height automatically, when soft keyboard appears on screen
    dialog.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);
    return dialog;
}
```

The `Fragment` that initiates the `DialogFragment` has a method that looks like this:

```
public void addLogButtonOnClickEvent() {
    LogEditFragment addLog = LogEditFragment.get(0l);
    if(mIsLargeLayout) {
        // The device is using a large layout, so show the fragment as a dialog
        addLog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddLog");
    } else {
        // The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        // For a little polish, specify a transition animation
        transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
        // To make it fullscreen, use the 'content' root view as the container
        // for the fragment, which is always the root view for the activity
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content, addLog).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

As I said, this is working fine for the KitKat emulator. This is NOT working for the Lollipop emulator.  You can see that I am trying very hard to get the `DialogFragment` to do adjust resize. :-) Does anyone see what I am missing or doing wrong? Also, if there is code that I have neglected to include that would help to find a solution, the please let me know, and I will post that as well. Thank you for any insight you can provide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took a while before I discovered this answer. I had actually refactored my `DialogFragment` to be an `AppCompatActivity`. I then began to think that perhaps the Navigation Drawer set up for Android Lollipop was perhaps to blame for the problems I was experiencing with the `DialogFragment`. My MainActivity layout file for API level 21 and above uses a `DrawerLayout` widget with a `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` for the Navigation Drawer view. So, both the `DrawerLayout` and the `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout` utilize `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in their definition as part of achieving the Material Design UI specification for a Navigation Drawer. That `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the `DrawerLayout` definition was interfering with the `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` defined for the MainActivity in the AndroidManifest.xml file to cause the dialog to adjust and resize when the soft keyboard is launched. Here is the XML layout of the MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- The Main Content View -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            layout="@layout/app_bar_main" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_main_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/app_bar" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <!-- The Navigation Drawer View -->
    <com.ahappydevelopment.android.fishtales.widgets.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scrimInsetsFrameLayout"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:insetForeground="#4000">

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer_container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.ahappydevelopment.android.fishtales.widgets.ScrimInsetsFrameLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

When telling the FragmentManager to add the `DialogFragment`, I was using the `android.R.id.content` as the view container, which is prescribed by the documentation. By experimenting with which view container to use, I was able to find one that gave the expected results. In my case, it is the `DrawerLayout` view defined in the MainActivity layout file.

```
LogEditFragment addLog = LogEditFragment.get(0l);
if(mIsLargeLayout) {
    // The device is using a large layout, so show the fragment as a dialog
    addLog.show(getFragmentManager(), "AddLog");
} else {
    // The device is smaller, so show the fragment fullscreen
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    // For a little polish, specify a transition animation
    transaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    // To make it fullscreen, use the 'drawer_layout' view 
    // as the container for the fragment
    transaction.add(R.id.drawer_layout, addLog).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Once I had made these changes and refactored my `LogEditFragment` class to once again extend `DialogFragment`, both the dialog and the navigation drawer behaved as expected.